# How do I teach Automapper to map X to IContainer<Y>?

Tags: c#, automapper, mvvmcross

This came up mapping from models to mvvmcross viewmodels, where you have some container classes you might use, for example:

```
namespace MvvmCross.Binding
{
  interface INC<T>
  {
    T Value { get; set; }
  }
}
class model
{
  String name { get; set; }
  DateTime when { get; set; }
  othermodel data { get; set; }
}
class viewmodel
{
  INC<String> Name { get; set; }
  INC<String> When { get; set; }
  INC<otherviewmodel> Data { get; set; }
}
```

- I need to teach AutoMapper to map from `A` to `INC<B>` (and back), without specifiying A or B.
- Null destination `INC<>` should be created, non-null should not be re-created.
- Mapping should continue such that `destination.Value = Mapper.Map<A,B>(source)`.
- Mapping `null --> INC<T>` should result in `INC<T>.Value = SomeDefaultValue`

Comment: Try [a simple object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/094a2c1456c9a3e916726a9aa60ddb2dc07cf66d/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L69).

Comment: I tried a generic `INCMapper<A,B> : ObjectMapper<A,INC<B>>` in combination with `ForAllPropertyMaps` and `MakeGenericType`, which didn't appear to work.  There is also `: ObjectMapper<Object,Object>` would need reflection to perform the mapping, is this what you mean?

Comment: You only need the mapper, none of the existing code. Yes, you need reflection. I'm not sure whether there is a better way. You can try a map from object to the open generic, but I'm not sure that's any better. If performance is a problem, you can use expressions, like [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/NullableDestinationMapper.cs), but of course that's more involved.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm looking at `ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression`, the last two lines can return an expression equivilant to `if(source!=null) return (DestType)source`, that cant be right?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Ok no problem, I've updated the question.

Comment: I would start with reflection. When that works, switch to expressions. If you think you found an AM bug, we need a simple repro for AM, not for your own code.

Comment: [Here's the shortest repro I could come up with](https://gist.github.com/flavourous/5e2cc704b66d55dcbc2fe89a6584d98c). I'll put some answers in for the approaches that are working.

Comment: new TypePair(typeof(String), typeof(Destination))

Comment: Yes my mistake - I've corrected the gist, it still fails though.

Comment: My understanding is that `IObjectMapper.MapExpression` should return an expression that can map `TSource` to `TDestination`, maybe I've got that wrong.  `AutoMapper.Mappers.AssignableMapper`, which ends up called in my example, actually returns `sourceExpression` rather than `Expression.Assign(destinationExpression, sourceExpression)`.  That said, then I don't understand how `NullableDestinationMapper` is working.

Comment: Source will never be null in an object mapper. So you know the destination type from the source type. The mapper should return the rhs expression, the source for the AssignableMapper. The NullableDestinationMapper relies on the source not being null, so it just maps the underlying types.

Comment: I want to map A => IContainer<B>, so I don't know the destination type if it's null.

Source can be null in `A source=null; INC<B> dest = null;  Mapper.Map<A,INC<B>>(source,dest); dest.Value == default(B);` and variants of that.  Of course this is only possible for reference source types - I see how `NullableDestinationMapper` gets around this, thanks.

If the destination is a non-null `INC<>`,  I don't want a rhs of type `INC<>` assigned and replacing it, i'd want the existing `.Value` to be set.  So I guess I need to change the lhs it's using.

Comment: If you have a repro where source is null _inside_ your mapper, we will fix it. We can add the destination type if you can't deduce it (a PR is even better :)). The workaround is to pass a destination object, as you've seen.

Comment: You're right, AutoMapper will not attempt to map null source values (which is something I need) [here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/flavourous/0c6237340261bac7ed592da0ae27afb8)

Comment: Then you need a map. But maybe you should consider what AM is doing for you. Because you might be better off mapping by hand. I mean surely it can be done, but is it worth it? :)

Comment: A map it is!  I think I was having trouble understanding the type of expression to return, I didn't realise it should *actually perform the mapping*, and that MapExpression just gives you a result to assign and doesn't do the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `ForAllMaps`, you can get the source/destination types and provide a closed, fully generic converter type.  This doesn't help if you want to directly call -`Map<X,IContainer<Y>`, but you shouldn't need to.

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<model, viewmodel>().ReverseMap();
    c.ForAllMaps((p, mc) =>
    {
        Type st = p.SourceType, sct = GetContained(st);
        Type dt = p.DestinationType, dct = GetContained(dt);
        if (sct != null) mc.ConvertUsing(typeof(TCReverse<,>).MakeGenericType(sct, dt));
        if (dct != null) mc.ConvertUsing(typeof(TCForward<,>).MakeGenericType(st, dct));
    });
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
Mapper.Map<viewmodel>(new model());
Mapper.Map<model>(new viewmodel());
```

With the simple converters:

```
public class TCReverse<X,Y> : ITypeConverter<IContainer<X>, Y>
{
    public Y Convert(IContainer<X> source, Y destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var use = source == null ? default(X) : source.Value;
        return context.Mapper.Map(use, destination);
    }
}

public class TCForward<X,Y> : ITypeConverter<X, IContainer<Y>>
{
    public IContainer<Y> Convert(X source, IContainer<Y> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
            destination = new Container<Y>();
        destination.Value = context.Mapper.Map(source, destination.Value);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

And I used a helper method here:

```
Type GetContained(Type t)
{
    return t.GetInterfaces()
            .Concat(new[] { t })
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
            .Where(x => typeof(IContainer<>).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            .Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments[0])
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Lucians help in the comments.

These mappers will work for `Mapper.Map<INC<String>>("test")`, but not for `Mapper.Map<String, INC<String>>(null, new NC<String>("I shouldnt be here"))`, since AutoMapper won't send a null source value.

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.Mappers.Insert(0, new DestinationObjectContainerMapper());
    c.Mappers.Insert(0, new SourceObjectContainerMapper());
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

public class DestinationObjectContainerMapper : BlackBoxObjectMapper
{
    bool InterfaceMatch(Type x) => x.IsGenericType && typeof(INC<>).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    Type CType(Type cdt) => cdt.GetInterfaces().Concat(new[] { cdt }).Where(InterfaceMatch).Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments[0]).FirstOrDefault();
    public override bool IsMatch(TypePair context) => CType(context.DestinationType) != null;

    public override object Map(object source, Type sourceType, object destination, Type destinationType, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dcType = CType(destinationType);

        // Create a container if destination is null
        if (destination == null)
            destination = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NC<>).MakeGenericType(dcType));

        // This may also fail because we need the source type
        var setter = typeof(INC<>).MakeGenericType(dcType).GetProperty("Value").GetSetMethod();
        var mappedSource = context.Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, dcType);

        // set the value
        setter.Invoke(destination, new[] { mappedSource });
        return destination;
    }
}
public class SourceObjectContainerMapper : BlackBoxObjectMapper
{
    bool InterfaceMatch(Type x) => x.IsGenericType && typeof(INC<>).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    Type CType(Type cdt) => cdt.GetInterfaces().Concat(new[] { cdt }).Where(InterfaceMatch).Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments[0]).FirstOrDefault();
    public override bool IsMatch(TypePair context) => CType(context.SourceType) != null;

    public override object Map(object source, Type sourceType, object destination, Type destinationType, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // this is only obtainable if destination is not null - so this will not work.
        var scType = CType(sourceType);

        // destination could also be null, this is another anavoidable throw
        object sourceContainedValue = null;
        if (source != null)
        {
            var getter = typeof(INC<>).MakeGenericType(scType).GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod();
            sourceContainedValue = getter.Invoke(source, new Object[0]);
        }

        // map and return
        return context.Mapper.Map(sourceContainedValue, scType, destinationType);
    }
}
```

This uses a slightly extended ObjectMapper:

```
public abstract class BlackBoxObjectMapper : IObjectMapper
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo MapMethod = typeof(BlackBoxObjectMapper).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("Map");

    public abstract bool IsMatch(TypePair context);

    public abstract object Map(object source, Type sourceType, object destination, Type destinationType, ResolutionContext context);

    public Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap,
        PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression,
        Expression contextExpression) =>
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(this),
            MapMethod,
            sourceExpression,
            Expression.Constant(sourceExpression.Type),
            destExpression,
            Expression.Constant(destExpression.Type),
            contextExpression);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Lucians help in the comments.  This mapper using expressions works, and will receive null values to map as required with a bit of help from [this patch](https://github.com/flavourous/AutoMapper/tree/allowMapperSourceNull) and `IObjectMapperInfo.CanMapNullSource = true`.

The AM team spent a lot of effort avoiding passing expressions that evaluate to null to Mappers, and it definitely simplifies the AutoMapper.Mappers namespace, so this patch is obviously controversial.  I thought about less intrusive ways to signal this like a `NullSafeExpression`, or an anonymous interface moniker like `interface ICanHandleNullSourceExpressions {}` to try to stem the flow, but I didn't find anything that looks better yet.

```
public class ContainerDestinationMapper : BaseContainerMapper, IObjectMapperInfo
{

    readonly Func<Type, Expression> createContainer;

    public bool CanMapNullSource => true;

    public ContainerDestinationMapper(Type GenericContainerTypeDefinition, String ContainerPropertyName, Func<Type, Expression> createContainer)
        : base(GenericContainerTypeDefinition, ContainerPropertyName)
    {
        this.createContainer = createContainer;
    }
    public bool IsMatch(TypePair context) => ContainerDef(context.DestinationType) != null;

    public Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap,
        PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression,
        Expression contextExpression)
    {

        var dparam = DigParameter(destExpression);
        var dVal = Expression.Property(dparam, dparam.Type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Value"));
        var cdt = ContainerDef(destExpression.Type);
        var tp = new TypePair(sourceExpression.Type, cdt);
        var ret = Expression.Block
                    (
                        // make destination not null
                        Expression.IfThen
                        (
                            Expression.Equal(dparam, Expression.Constant(null)),
                            Expression.Assign(dparam, createContainer(cdt))
                        ),
                        // Assign to the destination
                        Expression.Assign
                        (
                            dVal,
                            ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression // what you get if you map source to dest.Value
                            (
                                configurationProvider,
                                profileMap,
                                tp,
                                sourceExpression,
                                contextExpression,
                                null,
                                dVal,
                                true
                            )
                        ),
                        destExpression
                    // But we need to return the destination type!
                    // Sadly it will go on to assign destExpression to destExpression.
                    );
        return ret;
    }
    public TypePair GetAssociatedTypes(TypePair initialTypes)
    {
        return new TypePair(initialTypes.SourceType, ContainerDef(initialTypes.DestinationType));
    }
}

public class ContainerSourceMapper : BaseContainerMapper, IObjectMapperInfo
{
    public bool CanMapNullSource => true;

    public ContainerSourceMapper(Type GenericContainerTypeDefinition, String ContainerPropertyName)
        : base(GenericContainerTypeDefinition, ContainerPropertyName) { }

    public bool IsMatch(TypePair context) => ContainerDef(context.SourceType) != null;

    public Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap,
        PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression,
        Expression contextExpression)
    {
        var dstParam = DigParameter(destExpression);
        return Expression.Block(
            Expression.IfThenElse
            (
                Expression.Equal(sourceExpression, Expression.Constant(null)),
                Expression.Assign(dstParam, Expression.Default(destExpression.Type)),
                Expression.Assign(dstParam,
                    ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression(configurationProvider, profileMap,
                        new TypePair(ContainerDef(sourceExpression.Type), destExpression.Type),
                        Expression.Property(sourceExpression, sourceExpression.Type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(containerPropertyName)),
                        contextExpression,
                        propertyMap,
                        destExpression
                    )
                )
            ),
            dstParam
        );
    }

    public TypePair GetAssociatedTypes(TypePair initialTypes)
    {
        return new TypePair(ContainerDef(initialTypes.SourceType), initialTypes.DestinationType);
    }
}
public class BaseContainerMapper
{
    protected readonly Type genericContainerTypeDefinition;
    protected readonly String containerPropertyName;
    public BaseContainerMapper(Type GenericContainerTypeDefinition, String ContainerPropertyName)
    {
        genericContainerTypeDefinition = GenericContainerTypeDefinition;
        containerPropertyName = ContainerPropertyName;
    }
    protected ParameterExpression DigParameter(Expression e)
    {
        if (e is ParameterExpression pe) return pe;
        if (e is UnaryExpression ue) return DigParameter(ue.Operand);
        throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't find parameter");
    }
    public static Type ContainerDef(Type gen, Type to)
    {
        return new[] { to }.Concat(to.GetInterfaces())
                            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
                            .Where(x => gen.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
                            .Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments.Single())
                            .FirstOrDefault(); // Hopefully not overloaded!

    }
    protected Type ContainerDef(Type to)
    {
        return ContainerDef(genericContainerTypeDefinition, to);
    }
    protected PropertyInfo Of(Expression expr)
    {
        return expr.Type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(containerPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @lucian If you don't have any ideas on avoiding `NullCheckSource`, I'll try to come up with a PR.

Comment: As I've said, only a map will receive null, not a mapper. That's by design. So mappers don't have to handle this case. You're welcome to make a PR to change ObjectMapper to pass the types.

Comment: Sorry - I thought this was a map.  Which one do you mean by `map`?

Comment: CreateMap makes a map, you wrote an object mapper.

Comment: With CreateMap, there would need to be one for each combination of `A` and `B`, I am trying to avoid introspecting the types to decide what maps to make.  I've forked a patch that allows mappers to declare that they can handle null source values, what do you think?

Comment: No, we worked a lot to make object mappers not care about null :) You can create a map between object and the generic interface.

Comment: `CreateMap<object,INC<object>>` is not possible, because when the source or destination values are null, I cannot infer their types, as previously.  I will also be unable to take advantage of the performance gains on mapping at configuration time and avoiding reflection, if it becomes an issue.  I can maintain a fork I guess -- what happened to make you guys want the mappers not mapping everything?

Comment: It made the mappers simpler and the null handling easier to understand. Null and nullables are an important source of complexity in AM.

Comment: Ok - I don't see another way to solve the question, so I'll mark this as the answer.  Fwiw, you aren't loosing the internal null handling with a patch like this -- any mapper that insists it handle null source values is 'on it's own'.  Still open to alternative solutions, sorry to go against the grain here.

Comment: I would do it with ```CreateMap(typeof(oject), typeof(INC<>))```. The only thing you lose is the expression stuff.

Comment: Source type is unknown when it's null.  I also believe (last time I checked) that for CreateMap, both types have to be open (or both closed).

Comment: No, the map would work. It's true that when the source is null the type is unknown, but that's reasonable enough :) If both types would be generic, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example? We cannot make things like String open generic types :)  Also, `CreateMap(typeof(INC<object>), typeof(object))` doesn't work when destination is null, cant perform the inner mapping.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/d9abbd19689383ec9df6c16f70ae7850810148ad/src/UnitTests/Bug/GenericTypeConverter.cs

Comment: AM relies on types, but your only base type is object. That's a problem.

Comment: The base type is contextual, maybe we could add the type parameters to a non generic `ITypeConverter` and give it an `IsMatch` method? Perhaps we can pass `typeof(void)` to signify an open type in CreateMap?  This answer was a minimal edit to the AM source though, those two seem they'll go a bit deeper.

Answer (score 0):

[This patch](https://github.com/flavourous/AutoMapper/tree/feature/void-for-param) allows `typeof(void)` to be used in `CreateMap` to express a single parameter that is not contained within a type (i.e. it will match any type) and construct the `ITypeConverter` as such.

The alternative for an unpatched AutoMapper is to substitute `X` and `Y` with `object` in the below converters. I have added comments to the lines where this would fail.  Even ignoring these failings, such an attempt would require reflection and therefore be more complex and less performant.

```
Mapper.Initialise(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap(typeof(void), typeof(IContainer<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TCf<,>));
    cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IContainer<>), typeof(void)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TCb<,>));
});

class TCf<X, Y> : ITypeConverter<X, IContainer<Y>>
{
    public IContainer<Y> Convert(X source, IContainer<Y> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
        {
            // if Y was object we could not create the correct container type
            destination = new Container<Y>(); 
            destination.Configure();
        }
        // if Y was object and source was null, we could not map to the correct type
        destination.Value = context.Mapper.Map<Y>(source);
        return destination;
    }
}

class TCb<X, Y> : ITypeConverter<IContainer<X>, Y>
{
    public Y Convert(IContainer<X> source, Y destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // if X was object and source was null, we could not choose an appropriate default
        var use = source == null ? GetSomeDefault<X>() : source.Value;
        // if Y was object and destination was null, we could not map to the correct type
        return context.Mapper.Map<Y>(use);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lucian how do you feel about this one?

Comment: It seems to me that you can do all that with a map from object.

Comment: It doesn't work -- see the comments I've added to my answer.

Comment: You know the destination type inside your converter, you don't need an object instance. And the default source instance is null or the default for value types. The mapper solution would handle the defaults for you. Yes, you need reflection, but that's just because of the design of your types.

Comment: The destination type is unknown if it is `null` and the parameter type is `object` or `IContainer<object>`. It's common to have basic types on DAL objects and composite types on ViewModels, this one comes from MvvmCross. If you have an answer that works, please provide it.

Comment: I've already linked to the relevant examples. When you map to IContainer<T>, your generic converter will receive that type parameter, so you know the destination type.

Comment: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/flavourous/a65e28f527df3f98f07f80b7b5816229) of your solution.  There's 3 problems with it that I've commented in the gist.  Is there anything wrong with my patch?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on an older version, that's why it throws. And yes, when the type is object and the object is null, there is no useful type, that makes sense :) The patch is just another extra if, that will always cover another case.

Comment: `(foo)context.Mapper.Map(someObject, typeof(bar), typeof(object))` for example, will fail in the reverse map since `foo` is not known.

Comment: In the forward map, `context.Mapper.Map(null, typeof(object), typeof(foo))` where source is `bar` will not use any maps defined for `bar --> foo` that I have made.

Comment: You say "when the type is object and the object is null there is no useful information", which I agree with.  However the type is not object, the _base type_ is object, the most derived type might for example be String, byte[], or some other ref type that I want to convert to/from.

Comment: Yes, but you can workaround it. For the null source you can use NullSubstitute or a resolver. For the null destination you can pass a destination object or, again, a resolver would know the destination type. It doesn't make much sense to complicate the main path for corner cases. It's ok to add the types as parameters to the ObjectMapper. That's a more obscure and advanced API.

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/flavourous/be67fc2fc3b9a9f47c2dfaa6116947b9) of the workaround, It's a good idea but I don't feel safe using it with the problems it causes :/ (commented them in the gist again).

Comment: ObjectMapper also needs a null substitute on the source values (so that it gets called when source is null), so it faces the same issues for object sources even with type arguments.

Comment: Yes, that sounds just about right, but I think you can live with those :) Another way I didn't consider until now. You can omit the object->open generic map. Then AM will create the maps for you. You can customize those with ForAllMaps and use a generic converter which knows all the types you need. This seems better, but you need to work out the details.

Comment: I don't see how rogue DAL writes are avoidable [gist](https://gist.github.com/david-higgins/ec22d580ea4b40ddd9655dfa276ee6ad), as an example of one of the ways substitutes are making me uncomfortable.  I'll take a look at the ForAllMaps approach, I don't like not being able to do a direct `Mapper.Map<T,INC<Y>>`, but I can't think of a reason other than testing to want to do that.  Keeping a `Dictionary<Type,Object> { { typeof(String), "ReallyUnlikelyStringToWant" }, ... }` is a way, but it's madness, there are a lot of types!

Comment: if my object resolver could resolve to `NullSubClass<String>()`, without AM attempting to cast that to the destination type before passing it to my `typeconverter<object,..>`, it could be signalled that way.  Seems like another risky core change though.

Comment: Mapping both ways is always tricky. This just adds another hassle. You can rely on object identity to manufacture null like values. With dynamic mapping, you can also map directly and add the maps at runtime, but then you need what we call [inline maps](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html). ForAllMaps is simpler.

Comment: Yep - ForAllMaps does the job.  I'll post that as the answer.  Thanks!