# How do I teach Automapper to project X to IContainer<Y>?

Tags: automapper

For the same reasons as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249527/how-do-i-teach-automapper-to-map-x-to-icontainery/48467405#48467405), I would like to teach automapper to project into `INC<>` of `vmodel` below (and not back in this case), during something like `SomeContext.GetIQueryable<model>().ProjectTo<vmodel>()`

```
public interface INC<T>     { T Value { get; set; } }
public class NC<T> : INC<T> { public T Value { get; set; } }
public class model  { public int value { get; set; } }
public class vmodel { public IC<String> Value { get; set; } }
```

I'm trying to do it generically in here: https://gist.github.com/flavourous/9a2668daa41cfedb8359b26eac319df2

Here's me trying to do it explicitly: https://gist.github.com/flavourous/d35bac140bb2883ebd82846a2b75ec7e

Here's the problems I'm hitting:

## Cannot cast inside nongeneric `ProjectUsing` of `ForAllMaps`

When calling ProjectUsing inside ForAllMaps, the argument is of type `Expression<Func<object,object>>`.

`ProjectUsing((object src)=>new NC<String>("test"))` works fine, but any cast on `object src` give me [Rewriting child expression..is not allowed because it would change the meaning of the expression](https://gist.github.com/flavourous/f97429b2ec0d31fc0533c2773072ebfe).

## How to generate an expression mapping to the inner type?

AM needs to map the ProjectUsing expression to a query expression for the `IQueryable` it translates from the source `IQueryable`, and I want to express the conversion expression of `X->Y` that it would normally do if the `INC<>` wasn't there.

`Mapper.Configuration.ExpressionBuilder.GetMapExpression<,>()` looks like an option but I can't get a `ExpressionBuilder` inside `Initialise`?

Comment: Why would you mix ProjectUsing with Map, that doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: Hello again! I have a feeling you know why, thanks for helping :). I want to configure the way IC<> is projected to in the above, any suggestions? I don’t know why ProjectUsing offers me an object expression an then goes on to pass a different source type and won’t allow me to cast. Should it simply be ProjectUsing(LambdaExpression expression) inside Forallmaps?

Comment: ProjectTo is executed in the database, that means you cannot call Map. So I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you're on the wrong path.

Comment: My stumbling block is the cast, not the map, but i see what you mean. I want to teach AM to project to .Value

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question.  I don't really want to call Map, I want to generate the equivilant mapping expression, which I presume there is the facility for since that's what ProjectTo does if ProjectUsing is not configured.

Comment: ProjectUsing will be used for the mapping too. So you just need the right expression. Start with a concrete example, see if it works in SQL and then you can think about making it generic.

Comment: Not sure how you mean to do it in sql, the destination wouldn't ever go into a db, you mean like a subquery that returns something that has the structure of the viewmodel?  I've added a simple example, still cant find how to continue the mapping inside projectusing, but `GetMapExpression` looks promising..  I'll carry on with this.

Comment: ProjectTo generates a LINQ statement that gets translated to SQL, so, in plain LINQ, what are you trying to generate, does the DB provider support that? GetMapExpression is not an API, maybe you want to map expressions.

Comment: Ok, so the provider will be the one constructing the destination type, even though it will not correspond to a model it knows about?

Comment: Mapping expressions would be a way to go also, I could take the expression from destination queryable, map it and execute on source queryable then use the mapper on the results...

Comment: ProjectTo only makes sense as a SQL query.

Comment: I’m using a link queryable backing for these examples too, so I can’t really come up with a query, but that implies the problems I’m hitting are not to do with the query provider.

Comment: Surely it works with any query provider, not just sql?

Comment: You can use it however you want, but you're on your own.

Comment: Ok, my backing is ‘new List<model>().AsQueryable()’ at this post by which supports all expressions, so this isn’t an issue with the dB provider at this point.

Comment: :) That may be, but as I've said before, this is not a use case we care about with AM.